# Threejs too slow rendering leads that the browers can't response

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, rendering

I have used ThreeJS to draw a 3D scene. The 3D scene includes ten thousand of particles which are distributed according to some layout. By Threejs, the particles in 3D world can be rendered easily. But I have a problem. The brower will show  blank for 30s,during the process of rendering. The time of 30s is so unfriendly for users.

Can any one tell me how to solve the question about so long rendering time? or how can improve the efficiency of rendering? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: When does the blank screen exactly appear ? Before the first frame is rendered ?

Comment: If you don't show any code, it's difficult to diagnose. In addition, which browser are you using? Performance is way different between browsers

Comment: The blannk screen appeared before the first frame is rendered.

Comment: The brower is chrome

Comment: If render time is taking that long, chances are you are not caching geometries and/or materials. Any help you get here will be a guess without posting code.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without watching code. If the delay reason is javascript, you can measure it by benchmarks, for example console.time. But if the breaks are in your GPU, probably you should use less number of particles

Comment: The code is so long. Must to say, I have done traversal operation for three or four times.I'm not sure if it leads to the delay. But I have used console.log to print  information in every for circulation. The print information presentes more ealier than the render effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you add all of the particles in one go with (in example) a for loop, it kind of blocks the rendering loop. 
You could try to add all particles in batches of a thousand, untill you have reached your desired amount.